# How can i skip okhttp cache and get the response and cache the new response

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit with okHTTP cache for my network Calls, when i received a response i have written an interceptor to look for response body "timeToCache" value and re-write the cache header. I'm facing an issue now when I updated an enitity and call the get method it's always return me the cache response. to avoid that I added the below header to request

```
@GET("ws/something")
Something getSomething(@Header("Cache-Control") String cacheControl);
and then when calling you either supply null for a (maybe-)cached version or "no-cache" for a live version:

myApi.getSomething(forceRefresh ? "no-cache" : null);
```

now I'm getting the new response but this response not get cache? how can i save this response to cache now?

Comment: did you tried onlyIfCached() and maxStale() in your request ?

Comment: you mean do I need to set some request headers to get new response get cached

Comment: yes, just try this headers, FYI: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Cache.html

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a better way to solve this so i implmented remove cache entry method to remove the entry after the success of the update event.

```
 public void removeHTTPCacheEntry(final String cachedDelURL) {
    try {
        if (client != null && client.cache() != null && client.cache().urls() != null) {



            Iterator<String> cacheURlsItr = client.cache().urls();
            while (cacheURlsItr.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    URL cachedURL = new URL(cacheURlsItr.next());

                    String urlPath = cachedURL == null ? "" : cachedURL.getPath();


                    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(urlPath) && cachedDelURL.equals(urlPath)) {
                        cacheURlsItr.remove();

                        break;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException", e1);

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "removeHTTPCacheEntry", e1);
    }
}
```